Managing ROS2 params
I have a ros2 robot which needs to run across different warehouses with different environment configurations eg., door_height, corridor_length etc. I am using a NAV2 based architecture using plugins and BehaviorTree.CPP. What is a good way to manage :

Environment specific parameters
Bot specific parameters (eg., Situation where a bot type with a slightly larger wheel radius is used)

I want to keep a track of these parameters across different locations and load only the parameters specific to the location the bot is at.
Currently, I am making use of this repo. I have to specify the path to current config folder as an ENV variable. This is quite helpful as long as my robot has to stay in the same Warehouse, but if my robot has to transition between 2 different locations (It had loaded params for WareHouse 1 and now has moved into WH2), I am not quite sure how to do this since my robot has already loaded and is running with params from WH1. These params not only include the env specific changes (different door heights, different corridor lengths etc) but also plugins which means I might have to remove a previously loaded plugin and load, configure and activate a new one.
Has someone dealt with this situation before? It seems like such a trivial problem but I cannot seem to find a "clean" solution. I did come across parameter services in ROS2 which could help in changing param values, but that doesnt help me with the issue I have with the plugins.
Any help/ideas will be appreciated. Thanks!

I don't have an off-the-shelve solution, but rather some references:
generate_parameter_library is another relevant parameter library. It mentions support for dynamic parameters which might be of use in your context.
Alternatively, a possibility could be to read all parameter sets for all warehouses from the start (assuming each site has a limited number of warehouses) and swap the active parameter set based on the robot location. The swap could be triggered by the robot node itself, or from some external 'monitoring node' (see here).
There are some callback functions that can be used to evaluate and manipulate parameters when they are set, check the set_parameters_callback demo. As well as the other parameter demos.
